# What is your recommendation for using ordered logit regression?

Tags: r, regression, ordered-logit, polr

I'm estimated the effect of discrepancy of working hours on satisfaction of life, so I modeled an ordered logit regression using `MASS:polr` for my thesis. I created output tables for summary, brant, vif tolerance and also created effect plots using the effect package and correlation plots. Do you have any other suggestions? Do I also need to print the output for exp(coef) and marginal effects?
I would really appreciate any kind of answer, hint, link, book etc.

Comment: There are some examples and displays, also using polr, in Chapter 13, section 3 "Models for Ordinal Y" of this book https://www.routledge.com/Understanding-Regression-Analysis-A-Conditional-Distribution-Approach/Westfall-Arias/p/book/9780367493516

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will have a look at this book then.